# Weird transition when starting an activity with a synthetic backstack

Tags: java, android, animation, transition

I'm trying to start an activity from my splash that has a synthetic backstack:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
 Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ReaderActivity.class);
 startActivities(new Intent[]{intent, intent2});
 finish();
```

Everything works as expected except for the transition animation, it slides in instead of the default transition. How can i get the default fade transition for this?

I also tried the TaskStackBuilder, but this also has a weird animation. (I think it enforces the new activities to be started in a new task):

```
TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
.addNextIntentWithParentStack(new Intent(this, ReaderActivity.class))
.startActivities();
```

Comment: What does `startActivities` method do? How can one open 2 activities at the same time? I know its a method in Android but i could not find any useful guide to it.

Comment: It does exactly what it says.... starts multiple activities. I need to go to activity C from activity A in some cases. When the user presses the backbutton in C, i need to show activity B

Comment: So in your case, your current activity goes to `MainActivitiy` and then if the user presses the `back` button and then it comes back to `ReaderActivity` rather than the `Current` Activity. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: No it's the other way around. ReaderActivity is C and MainActivity is B